# dmenu top bar in xmonad runs some items (Chromium), but not ranger or others

Tags: bash, archlinux, xmonad

I have a "stock" xmonad install on Arch.

No changes to my xmonad.hs yet

I have installed dmenu.

It runs by alt-p, the default, and displays and filters as expected.

Chromium runs, but other items, like ranger, alsamixer or other tasks do not.

I am not finding anything anywhere about anyone having to do anything to get these items to run, nor anyone having any issues with doing so.

Surely, then, there is something wrong in my install.

my dmenu_run is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
dmenu_path | dmenu "$@" | ${SHELL:-"/bin/sh"} &
```

I would normally run terminology with bash or zsh. I have tried to alter the SHELL to `/bin/bash`, but to no avail.

Is there any other place I must look or items I should alter?

Such a shame as I am really liking xmonad so far, and want to get dmenu working before I start exploring xmonad.hs...

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: I have found the following 
[here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139319) over at Archwiki that involves changing dmenu_run and adding a .demenu_term in one's home. It seems to work, but still wonder if there was a more orthadox mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ranger` and `alsamixer` are applications which run inside a terminal. Imagine (or try) to run `ls` via `dmenu`, where should the directory listing be printed to without a terminal?

You look for functionality which is provided either by `prompt` imported from  [`XMonad.Prompt.Shell`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Prompt-Shell.html) by using a convinient keybinding like

```
((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_c), prompt ("xterm" ++ " -e") greenXPConfig)
```

(described in the linked documentation) or `shellPrompt` where you execute

```
xterm -e alsamixer
```

or any other command, e.g.

```
feh path/to/image/you/want/to/open/now.jpg
```

instead of opening a terminal, running above with tailing `&` and exiting the terminal.